# ValidationException vs ConstraintViolationException for validation

Tags: spring-boot, spring-restcontroller, spring-validator

I am trying to figure out which Exception (`ConstraintViolationException` or `ValidationException`) i have to used on `@ControllerAdvice`,
.

My controller is

```
@RequestMapping(value="/myUrl",method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String getMyData( @Valid @RequestBody MyObject myObject,BindingResult bindingResult ) {
```

And this is my ControllerAdvice class and i am not sure which exception to use.

```
   @ControllerAdvice
    public class ValidationAdviceClass{
        @ExceptionHandler(ValidationException.class or ConstraintViolationException.class )
        public ResponseEntity handleValidtionErrors(ValidationException ex or ConstraintViolationException) {

       // mycode
}
```

Searching i found someone saying use `MethodArgumentNotValidException`

I am confused with which type of exception to use.

Answer (score 0):

No exception is automatically thrown unless an error happened during the process of validation, for example (then a `ValidationException` would be thrown).

Any validation errors in your `RequestBody` would be passed to the `BindingResult` that you also have as a parameter of your function. Then it's up to you to decide if you want to throw an exception.

I suggest you read this [Spring Tutorial about Validating Form Input](https://spring.io/guides/gs/validating-form-input/) to better understand how you can achieve what you want.